# Threads with same argument objects give different values

Tags: multithreading, c++11

I have a problem where two threads with different functions and same argument objects result in giving different values for those objects.

To clearify, please observe the following code:

```
class Player(){
    // Definition of Player here
    // with get- and set functions
    // for a certain value.
}

class Game(){
    static void Draw(Player p){
        while(1){
            gotoxy(p.getValue(), 15);
            cout << p.name();
       }
    }

    static void Move(Player p){
        int x = p.getValue();
        while(1){
            if(_kbhit()){
                p.setValue(++x);
            }
        }
    }

    void startGame(){
        Player pl1(5);

        thread thd1(Move, pl1);
        thread thd2(Draw, pl1);
        thd1.join();
        thd2.join();
    }  

}
```

While the value 'x' is changing in the function 'Move' for every key stroke, when getting that value in function 'Draw' still has the initial value for 'pl1' (which is 5).

How can I get 'Draw' to aquire the same value that 'Move' has given?
I appreciate any help and guidance.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You just need to learn how to use threads. There isn't one quick and simple answer to this. You have to understand the entire concept of flows of execution that share address space. You need some sane way to share/exchange information between threads. It won't happen reliably all by itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing the player by value

```
static void Move(Player pl)
```

rather than by reference/pointer, so both functions have their own, local, *copies* of the original variable.

```
static void Move(Player& pl)
```

will take the variable by reference and give both functions access to the original variable.

Also, unless `getValue` and `setValue` implement some form of locking, this code is not thread safe.

Comment: even when passed by reference, an optimizing compiler could optimize out the call to `getValue` and the value change will be invisible in the reading thread; hence, thread synchronization is absolutely vital!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are passing pl1 by value, when you want to be passing it by reference. Even though it looks like you are passing pl1 into each function, what's really going on is that the Move and Draw threads are each constructing new Player objects. If you pass by references, then both threads will refer to the same object as opposed to creating their own copies. Try changing the signatures of the functions to the following:

```
static void Move(Player &p);
static void Draw(Player &p);
```

Also, consider putting some exit condition into your function. Since while(1) will never exit, the join() functions will wait forever. Hope that helps!